# Type Error: string indices must be integers

Tags: python

I'm very new to coding and as a school project I was trying to create a Cesar code, I got it working but then I tried to reverse it, so it could decode. I thought it was as simple as subtracting the jump but then it came up with this:

```
entrada=input("Please input your Message:")
matriz= "abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwyz 1234567890"

salida=''

for letra in entrada:
 posicion = matriz.find(letra.lower())
 salto = posicion
 posicion = posicion-salto

 if posicion > len(matriz) -1:
  posicion=posicion-len(matriz)

 if posicion < len(matriz) +1:
  posicion = posicion+len(matriz)

 salida = salida+matriz[posicion]


print (salida)
```

After this, it came back with the error in line 18

Comment: Please include the _full_ error message.

Comment: You're setting `salto` to the value of `posicion` (line 8) and immediatly after that, you set the value of `posicion` to `posicion-salto`; that its value will always be zero (0).

Comment: I get an `IndexError: string index out of range` with your code, not a `TypeError`.

Comment: Important: Are you using ancient Python 2 or modern Python 3? The way `input()` works changed between the two!

Answer (score 0):

```
salto = posicion
posicion = posicion-salto
```

after this your posicion is 0 whatever salto and posicion you have had before.

```
 if posicion < len(matriz) +1:
    posicion = posicion+len(matriz)
```

Here you get posicion which is greater than len(matriz), so matriz[position] results in IndexError

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

```
salto = posicion
posicion = posicion-salto
```

will make `posicion` 0, no matter what. Perhaps, you're missing a piece of code here. Also, your code is returning `IndexError: string index out of range` at line 17, `salida = salida + matriz[posicion]`. There is no type error.